# when a set of roots extend to a system of simple roots

Tags: rt.representation-theory, root-systems

Given a set of roots in a root system, assume that the pairing of each two roots in this set is not positive. Then clearly the set gives a closed root subsystem. My question is, when this set extends to a system of simple roots in the original root system. Of course, it is not always true, for example taking closed subsystem of long roots in B_2. Is it true for any simply-laced case.  We are particularly interested in the exceptional type E_6.

Comment: By the way, it's unclear what you mean by "the set **gives** a closed root subsystem."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_6$ be the simple roots of $E_6$, and suppose that $\alpha_3$ is the root corresponding to the trivalent node of the Dynkin diagram. Let $\theta$ be the highest (positive) root. Then $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_4,\alpha_5,\alpha_6,-\theta\}$ is a system of simple roots for a root system of type $A_2 \times A_2 \times A_2$, so it clearly does not extend to a system of simple roots for $E_6$.

This example is coming from [Borel-de Siebenthal theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93de_Siebenthal_theory), which basically says that the maximal rank sub-root systems of a root system are given by taking the [extended Dynkin diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_diagram#Affine_Dynkin_diagrams) of the Dynkin diagram, and deleting some node. The "affine node" of the extended Dynkin diagram corresponds to $-\theta$ the negative highest root.

(By the way, if you insist that the system of simple roots give an *irreducible* root system, then the answer changes in this case of $E_6$, because the only *connected* Dynkin diagrams we can get from the extended Dynkin diagram by deleting a node are of type $E_6$.)

EDIT: Let me mention a positive result, since you seem interested in that as well. Let $\Phi$ be a root system in a vector space $V$. Let $V'\subseteq V$ be a subspace spanned by a subset of roots. Set $\Phi' := \Phi\cap V'$, a sub-root system of $\Phi$. Let $S'$ be a system of simple roots for $\Phi'$. Then $S'$ can be extended to $S$, a system of simple roots for $\Phi$. This is for instance Bourbaki, "Lie groups and Lie algebras," Chapter VI, Section 1.7, Proposition 24.

Comment: Thanks.  If we already know the set of roots generates a root system whose Dynkin diagram is a subdiagram of E_6, can we conclude that this is a Levi subsystem of E_6?

Comment: @JJH: What does "Levi subsystem" mean?

Comment: It exactly means, the set of roots can be extended to a system of simple roots.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. My guess would be not necessarily. For instance, take $S=\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_4,\alpha_5,-\theta\}$, where $\alpha_6$ corresponds to the node adjacent to the affine node in the extended Dynkin diagram. Then $S$ is a system of simple roots for a Dynkin diagram of type $A_2\times A_2\times A_1$, which is a sub-diagram of $E_6$, but I don't see an obvious way to extend $S$ to a system of simple roots for all of $E_6$ (OTOH, I don't see why this is impossible either).

Comment: @JJH: see my edit for a positive result in this direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reference.